# How to update contents of a variable as the new element gets created

Tags: javascript

So in my code I have a situation similar to this case, where a new element gets added, but doesn't have functionality of an original elements. How can I update contents of a `btns` variable inside an `event()` function?

```js
event();

function event() {
  let btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');

  Array.from(btns).forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    e.currentTarget.style.color = "red";
    btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
  }));
  createElement();

}

function createElement() {
  let cont = document.getElementById('cont');
  let newBtn = document.createElement('p');
  newBtn.classList.add('btn');
  newBtn.textContent = "Btn4";

  let addBtn = document.getElementById('addBtn');
  addBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    cont.appendChild(newBtn);
  });

}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  <p class="btn">Btn1</p>
  <p class="btn">Btn2</p>
  <p class="btn">Btn3</p>
</div>
<p id="addBtn">New Btn</p>
```

Comment: You don't need `Array.from(btns).forEach(`, you can use `for( const b of btns )`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_delegation) here. This means setting the event on one of the parent elements, for example the container `#cont`.

When `#cont` or an element inside is clicked you check if that element matches your criteria. If this is the case execute your event.

Event delegation allows for the addition of inner elements without adding or changing of events, since the event is placed on the outer container.

```js
const cont   = document.getElementById("cont");
const addBtn = document.getElementById("addBtn");

cont.addEventListener("click", ({target}) => {
  if (!target.matches(".btn")) return;
  target.style.color = "red";
});

addBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const newBtn   = document.createElement("p");
  const btnCount = cont.querySelectorAll(".btn").length;
  const textNode = document.createTextNode(`Btn${btnCount + 1}`);
  
  newBtn.classList.add("btn");
  newBtn.append(textNode);
  
  cont.append(newBtn);
});
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  <p class="btn">Btn1</p>
  <p class="btn">Btn2</p>
  <p class="btn">Btn3</p>
</div>
<p id="addBtn">New Btn</p>
```

Comment: I never thought of doing so, that's exactly what I needed, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
event();

function event() {
  let btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');

  Array.from(btns).forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
          e.currentTarget.style.color = "red";
          btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
  }));
  
  let addBtn = document.getElementById('addBtn');
  addBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
          createElement();
  });  
}

function createElement() {
  let cont = document.getElementById('cont');
  let newBtn = document.createElement('p');
  newBtn.setAttribute('class', 'btn');
  newBtn.textContent = "Btn" + (document.querySelectorAll('.btn').length + 1);
  newBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
          e.currentTarget.style.color = "red";
  });
  cont.appendChild(newBtn);
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  <p class="btn">Btn1</p>
  <p class="btn">Btn2</p>
  <p class="btn">Btn3</p>
</div>
<p id="addBtn">New Btn</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Iam not 100% sure I understand your need correctly. But if you want to define a function which should be fired after specific event on elements, that are not part of the page on load. For example you load a page, you click a button and create a new element and then you click on the element.
If this is the case you can use something like this (jQuery):

```
$(function(){
 $("#cont").on("click", ".btn", function(){
   alert("clicked") 
 }
})
```

In this case, it does not matter if there is any element with btn class on page load.

Comment: Yes, that's what I need. Although I don't know jQuery, it would be nice to have the same in raw javascript

Comment: I see. I am not fan of raw JS so I dont know syntax that well. But I assume you can use similar approach. Meaning you add event listener to parent container and then you check what element was actually clicked, and if it equals an element with a specific class, you do whatever you wanted to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

- Add variable to hold new button number like `var btnIndex = 4;`
- Add one function to handle click event for `p` like in below `pClick`.
- Inside `event()` assign click to existing `.btn` with `Array.from(btns).forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', pClick));`.
- Update `addBtn` click event function and move `let newBtn = document.createElement('p');` inside it.
- Assign click vent to `newBtn` with `newBtn.addEventListener('click', pClick);`
- Use `btnIndex++;` after adding new `newBtn`.

Try it below.

```js
var btnIndex = 4;
event();

function pClick(e) {
  e.currentTarget.style.color = "red";    
}

function event() {
  let btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
  Array.from(btns).forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', pClick));
  createElement();
}

function createElement() {
  let cont = document.getElementById('cont');
  let addBtn = document.getElementById('addBtn');
  
  addBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {    
    let newBtn = document.createElement('p');
    newBtn.textContent = "Btn" + btnIndex;
    newBtn.addEventListener('click', pClick);
    cont.appendChild(newBtn);
    btnIndex++;
  });

}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  <p class="btn">Btn1</p>
  <p class="btn">Btn2</p>
  <p class="btn">Btn3</p>
</div>
<p id="addBtn">New Btn</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do here. but if want to add a new paragraph by clicking on the New Btn para you can do something like this

```
event();

function event() {
  let btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');

  Array.from(btns).forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    e.currentTarget.style.color = "red";
    btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
  }));
  createElement();

}

function createElement() {

  let newBtn = document.createElement('p');
  let textNode=document.createTextNode('Btn4')
  newBtn.appendChild(textNode)
  let addBtn = document.getElementById('addBtn');
  addBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
     cont.appendChild(newBtn);
     })

  // let cont = document.getElementById('cont');
  // let newBtn = document.createElement('p');
  // newBtn.textContent = "Btn4";

  // let addBtn = document.getElementById('addBtn');
  // addBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  //   cont.appendChild(newBtn);
  // });

}
  </script>
```